# Is it possible to store a String in a HashMap for a certain period of time

Tags: java, string, arraylist, time, hashmap

So I am fairly new to java but I had a question :
Would It be possible to store a String in an ArrayList for a certain period of time, or would I have to store it in a HashMap but if I do store it in a HashMap I don't know how to make it so I can store it for a certain period of time.

Comment: Try to break down the problem: do you know how to put something into a HashMap? Do you know how to take something out of it? Do you know how to perform an action after a certain amount of time (a quick search online for that phrase finds several hits)? Those would be your starting blocks. Note that this almost definitely involves multithreading, which is itself a complex topic -- this problem might not be a good place to start, if you're new to Java (or programming in general).

Comment: FYI you're getting downvoted because you're not making a lot of sense (what gave you the impression a `HashMap` would solve this problem?) and it's not clear what research you've done or what you've tried thus-far. Adding more context about what you're actually trying to accomplish, along with more detail about what you understand about these classes, would help make this a better question. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more.

Answer (score 1):

**Note: Storing stuff in a hash map/array list only for an amount of time sounds like an XY problem. There's probably a better way to achieve your ultimate goal. But if you insist, here's how.**

There's something called `javax.swing.Timer`. It is very useful if you want to measure time.

First, let's create an `ArrayList`:

```
final ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();

arr.add("Hello");
```

That's pretty simple, no need to explain.

Then, we create the timer:

```
final Timer t = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        t.stop();
        arr.remove("Hello");
    }
});
```

It's a *little* bit complicated here. The constructor of `Timer` takes 2 arguments. The first is the delay of the timer, in milliseconds. Here I wrote 1000 so it will remove the item from the array after one second. The second argument is the thing that it will do after the delay. In this case, we tell it to stop the timer first (because we only want to run this once) and remove the item.

After creating the timer, we need to *start* the timer of course!

```
t.start();
```

And BOOM! The array will only hold `"Hello"` for one second!

Answer (score -1):

You can store string in an array list or for that matter in any Java Collection like list,Map,Queue etc. are capable of storing string,Integer,Double etc. along with objects of user defined classes.To do so use, List listObj = new ArrayList(yourArrayListSize);